# DVD Drive USB Full Eject

Tags: usb, external-drive

I don't know if this is the place to ask this question.

I am trying to look for a usb dvd drive that has a full eject tray.  I want the tray to eject all the way out the same way that my tower does.  How do I search for this kind of usb drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a 3.5" External USB enclosure with an external access on it. Then you can get a desktop optical drive, put it in there and be done with it.

Here's an enclosure that's sort of close to what you need: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sumvision-Apex-inch-SATA-Enclosure/dp/B004LX186C/ref=pd_sim_computers_15